# Evitar ver datos de JWT en su consola

Tags: seguridad, jwt

Estoy empezando a trabajar con JWT.

Estoy integrándolo en un proyecto Web, por lo tanto veo las llamadas HTTPS en la consola y con ello, sus respuestas (en JWT)

Me parece que es una funcionalidad buenísima para ofuscar los datos, pero le veo un gran fallo de seguridad, ¿Cómo es posible que copie esa respuesta, la pegue en su web y vea los datos sin poner la firma? Esta claro que pone firma inválida, pero se ve todo el dato de la respuesta.

¿Es porque estoy haciendo algo mal? ¿O realmente JWT es tan inseguro?

Comment: Para que cosa estás tratando de usar JWT?

Comment: Uso JWT para ofuscar todas las respuestas de mi API

Comment: No estás dando mucha explicación, pero JWT no es para ofuscar información.

Comment: Que otra tecnología recomendarías tu pues para ofuscar los datos de la respuesta?

Comment: Insisto que no es claro lo que estás haciendo, por favor editá la pregunta y explicá con más detalle lo que querés hacer. Y tené presente que ofuscar no es lo mismo que encryptar, en caso de que sea esto a lo que realmente te referís. Ofuscar es hacer algo mas dificil de entender. Encriptar es hacer algo inentendible para todos aquellos que no tengan una clave para volverlo entendible.